# Tabela Dinâmica com Ajax e JSP

Tags: javascript, mysql, java-ee

Estou aprendendo Java Web e gostaria de saber se poderiam me ajudar no seguinte: Possuo um formulário que insiro dados no banco, e embaixo dele uma tabela no qual realizo a listagem do que foi inserido no banco, porém o que acontece é o seguinte, estou tentando inserir um dado no banco por esse campo, só que queria que a linha da tabela atualizasse de maneira assíncrona. Alguém poderia ajudar?

Esse código só está enviando uma mensagem como resposta pois tinha tentado outras maneiras e como baguncei resolvi deixar assim mesmo por enquanto.

**Index.jsp:**

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function salvar() {
                var descricao = $("input[name=descricao]").val();
                $.post("TextoServlet", {descricao: descricao})
                        .done(function (data) {
                            descricao = $("input[name=descricao]").val('');
                            $("#mensagem").html(data);
                        });
                return false;
            }


        </script>
        <title>JSP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Texto</h1>
            <form action="TextoServlet" method="post" onsubmit="return salvar()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nome">Descrição:</label>
                    <input id="nome" type="text" name="descricao">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                        Salvar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>


            <jsp:useBean id="dao" class="modelo.TextoDAO"></jsp:useBean>
            <div id="mensagem">
                Aqui está aparecendo a mensagem!
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Codigo</th>
                        <th>Descricao</th>
                        <th>Alterar</th>
                        <th>Excluir</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody>

                    <c:forEach var="txt" items="${dao.listar}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${txt.codigo}</td>
                            <td>${txt.descricao}</td>
                            <td><button>Alterar</button></td>
                            <td><button>Deletar</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

E aqui está o **Servlet:**

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import modelo.Texto;
import modelo.TextoDAO;

public class TextoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String acao = request.getParameter("acao");
        String codigo = request.getParameter("codigo");
        if (acao.equals("excluir")) {
            TextoDAO texto = new TextoDAO();
            int cod = Integer.parseInt(codigo);
            try {
                texto.excluir(cod);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                out.print("Excluido");
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //objeto acima para escrever na tela

        String descricao = request.getParameter("descricao");


        try {

            if (!descricao.equals("") && descricao != null) {
                Texto texto = new Texto();
                texto.setDescricao(descricao);
                TextoDAO dao = new TextoDAO();
                dao.salvar(texto);
                out.print("<p class='alert alert-info'>Salvo com Sucesso!</p>");

            }
            else {
                out.print("<p class='alert alert-warning'>Preencha o campo corretamente!</p>");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.print("<p class='alert alert-danger'>Erro ao salvar Texto</p>");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Poderia inserir na pergunta o código que você já implementou?

Comment: Não sei se mandei da maneira certa mas está ai

Answer (score 0):

Você ja pensou em usar Ajax? Eu passei pelo mesmo problema e com Ajax consegui resolver a questão da chamada assíncrona.
Recomendo o uso do Ajax com jquery.

Segue uma ótima referencia do uso de Ajax com Servlets:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax

Comment: Vou dar Uma olhada Muito obrigado!